Text with '&LT' in db displays as '<' in browser
Please advise how to avoid text with &LT in db displayed as < in browser

Which programming language or framework are you using to display the content of the database?

It sounds like you just want to "HTML encode" your value when outputting to the page.  Many frameworks/languages have that functionality built-in, or have a library available.

My suggestion would be to parse the value from your database and replace your &lt with &amp;lt before it gets parsed and rendered on the page.


<div>
    <p>Normal: &lt</p>
</div>

<div>
    <p>Adjusted: &amp;lt</p>
</div>



